Splitting into multiple dataframes if criteria is met
I am working on a small program and need some guidance.
Basically I am trying to read a CSV, put the attributes into a data frame and filter where "video = 1". This has been done.
What I cant figure out to do is splitting this data frame into multiple data frames. In the image below, I am looking to split it into two data frames when either the "count" is greater than 1, or the "Time" is greater than 100. Basically these are different recordings in the same log I need to split apart for analysis.
It might not happen in each log, it could happen 2+ times.
I am thinking of a For Loop to determine if the previous row is greater than the values I mentioned above, but I cant figure out making it work.
Any help is appreciated.


Does this mean you want one DF where Count >  1 and another DF where Time >100? What happens if both conditions are met? Note neither condition applies to your sample data, which should be provided as text not an image so it can be used for demonstration.

Basically I want to compare the two and split them.
It records every 100 millisends. So when the video stops, the log keeps recording.
It could be 5 minutes for example, until the next video. In the above, you see it stops at 800, then starts again.
For 400 - 800, that is 1 record. I want that to be 1 dataframe.
1600-2100 is what I want to put into a second dataframe.
Basically using either time or video. I need to figure out how to split it if Time compared to the previous record is greater than 100, or if the count is more than 1.

With your clarification that is the CHANGE in count or Time that you want to mark the separation then there are two issues: first to mark the separate parts of the DF and the split the parts using groupby; secondly to store the separated DFs. The first can be done using a condition and cumsum and the second by storing the separate DF's in a List.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ({ 'count': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
                     'Time': [400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 2100]
                     })

df['g'] = ((df['count'].diff().gt(1)) | (df['Time'].diff().gt(100))).cumsum()

grouped = df.groupby('g') #group the rows based on temp column 'g'

df_list = []
for g, dfg in grouped:
    df_list.append(dfg.drop('g', axis = 1).reset_index(drop = True))

The individual DFs can then be accessed using df[0] etc. and could be renamed as required.
print(df_list[0],'\n')
print(df_list[1])

which gives:
   count  Time
0      3   400
1      4   500
2      5   600
3      6   700
4      7   800 

   count  Time
0     15  1600
1     16  1700
2     17  1800
3     18  1900
4     19  2000
5     20  2100


That is amazing. Thank you so much. I was doing some sloppy work just filtering, creating lists, selecting the record that had (in this case) and 800ms difference from the last record.
